# Add a new element to a list of dictionaries with calculations based on other keys

Tags: python

I have a listo of dictionaries from json like the following :

```
{'input_data': '6_32667105_C_T',
 'chr_id': '6',
 'position': 32667105,
 'ref_allele': 'C',
 'alt_allele': 'T',
 'gene_id': 'ENSG00000237541',
 'fpred_max_score': None,
 'qtl_score': 9.52804561536107,
 'interval_score': None,
 'qtl_score_q': 0.7,
 'interval_score_q': None,
 'd': None,
 'distance_score': None,
 'distance_score_q': None}
```

I would like to add an element in each dictionary of a list with the name overall score which will be the result of the following formula :

```
score = (fpred_max_score Χ 1) + (distance_score_q Χ 0.33) + (interval_score_q Χ 0,33) + (qtl_score_q Χ 0,66) 
overall score = score / 2,32
```

In case of None the calculation considers the key as 0. for example here fpred_max_score = None so we will have 0.
What i managed to do is to read and create the new key in the list of dictionaries called overall_score

```
with open(exp+'.json') as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)
    
type(data1)
df = data1[0:2]

result = [dict(item, overall_score='value') for item in df]
```

How can i add the value based on the above description ?

Comment: why are you taking only 2 items from list: `data1[0:2]` ?

Comment: just to practice and be able to see them because the list is huge more than 8000

Answer (score 2):

Use *dict union* `|` operation:

```
# sample list of dicts
data = [{'input_data': '6_32667105_C_T',  'chr_id': '6',  'position': 32667105,  'ref_allele': 'C',  'alt_allele': 'T',  'gene_id': 'ENSG00000237541',  'type_id': 'eqtl',  'source_id': 'eqtl',  'fpred_labels': {'list': []},  'fpred_scores': {'list': []},  'fpred_max_label': None,  'fpred_max_score': None,  'qtl_score': 9.52804561536107,  'interval_score': None,  'qtl_score_q': 0.7,  'interval_score_q': None,  'd': None,  'distance_score': None,  'distance_score_q': None}]

res = [d | {'overall_score': (((d['fpred_max_score'] or 0) * 1) 
                              + ((d['distance_score_q'] or 0) * 0.33) 
                              + ((d['interval_score_q'] or 0) * 0.33) 
                              + ((d['qtl_score_q'] or 0) * 0.66)) / 2}
       for d in data]

print(res)
```

---

```
[{'alt_allele': 'T',
  'chr_id': '6',
  'd': None,
  'distance_score': None,
  'distance_score_q': None,
  'fpred_labels': {'list': []},
  'fpred_max_label': None,
  'fpred_max_score': None,
  'fpred_scores': {'list': []},
  'gene_id': 'ENSG00000237541',
  'input_data': '6_32667105_C_T',
  'interval_score': None,
  'interval_score_q': None,
  'overall_score': 0.23099999999999998,
  'position': 32667105,
  'qtl_score': 9.52804561536107,
  'qtl_score_q': 0.7,
  'ref_allele': 'C',
  'source_id': 'eqtl',
  'type_id': 'eqtl'}]
```

Comment: thank you it looks good and it seems to work !

Comment: how can i see in which place or res for example the fpred_max_score. is not Nope and there is number . I tried  `(sub['fpred_max_score'] !='Nope') for sub in res` but it returns on ly true or false

Comment: @Jim_13, "*in which place or res*" - post what do you expect as a result for that

Comment: fpred_max_score' is usually None but there are some entries that are not and i want to find those entries.So for example i would like to be able to print res[34] which i know that contains fpred_max_score' different than Nope for example 0,1

Comment: @Jim_13, `[d for d in res if d['fpred_max_score'] is not None]`. And why calling `None` as `'Nope'` ?

Comment: sorry my mistake :) thank you